# Applying an animation to a range of UILabel's attributedText

Tags: ios, animation, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'm trying to animate only part of an attributed string inside a `UILabel`.

For example, I have a message from my friend, saying "Tell @azjls9112knf to come here" (with @azjls9112knf is the *id* of another person in the server's database, which I need to ask the server for his name and display it later) - so while I'm waiting for the response from server, I want to animate the "@azjls9112knf" part of the text, so that end-user knows that something is being loaded from the server, after the name is successfully retrieved, I'll reload the text with the proper name

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: what kind of animation are you looking forward adding to that part of text?

Comment: Shimmer effect, probably?

Answer (score 0):

for moving text inside a label :

You can use pod 'MarqueeLabel/Swift' for moving text inside a label .With this pod you can move any text in any direction only setting its features i.e.
first you have to install pod and after installing add class to label in which you want to move text
Then make its outlet:

@IBOutlet weak var youLabel: MarqueeLabel!

and when you made outlet then you can use it in your own way i.e.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    trackName.type = .rightLeft
    trackName.animationCurve = .linear
    trackName.fadeLength = 10.0
    trackName.leadingBuffer = 30.0
    trackName.trailingBuffer = 20.0      
}
```